# JFrog Artifactory and Oracle repository

Tags: java, oracle, maven, artifactory

I've started to use JFrog Artifactory 4.14, my maven app needs an ojdbc jar which can be downloaded from oracle repository, which, if I use maven local settings, I'd setted from
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010

Now, using JFrog Artifactory, I've setted remote repo according to
http://buttso.blogspot.lt/2015/02/fronting-oracle-maven-repository-with.html https://www.jfrog.com/blog/fronting-oracle-maven-repository-artifactory/

[image]

[image]

TEST button says connection successful

I've replaced settings.xml file with the one JFrog Artifactory generated to me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>remote-repos</name>
      <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
      <id>remote-repos</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I've added to my POM

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>e44b4c0db643-releases</name>
        <url>http://docker.k***.l**:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

but when I try to run maven command

> clean install

I get

The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2, com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2: Could not find artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in remote-repos

Comment: You will never find thos artifacts in public repositories.

Comment: I don't understand Your comment??? These artifacts aren't in public repository, they are in oracles repsitory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a virtual repository in JFrog.  This will be a combination of other repositoies, this is the one you will point at in your settings.xml.

See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories

I suspect you will also need a proxy element in your settings.xml.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: I guess this was a problem, I've just added oracle repository to virtual repository and now seems that everything is working. I have nothing chenged in settings.xml, no proxies nothing..

Comment: @ArvisM can you please give some more detail on how to you resolved this. I've tried the same steps as you've laid out, including adding the maven-oracle remote repository to the releases and snapshot virtual repositories, but I still can't resolve Oracle libraries. I also can't use Artifactory to browse the maven-oracle repo like I can central. I've triple checked the remote repo settings, used the suggested settings from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings and still doesn't work. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

As You already have created You new Remote Repository You have to add it to Virtual Repository
[image]

choose New (or edit existing one)

[image]

and select repositories

[image]

that should be it